# Remove formatting (html tags) of string and add it again

Tags: javascript

Let's say there is a string that looks like this:
(number enclosed by HTML tags)

Example 1:

```
var string = "<b>123.34</b>";
```

It could also look something like that (enclosed by any other html tags)

Example 2:

```
var string = "<b><i>123.34</i></b>";
```

This replace is going to extract the number (or remove the html tags)

```
var stringNoTags = string.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```

Next I will format the number with a custom function (e.g. divide the number by 60 or apply any other mathematical operation)

What I want now is to put the number back into the HTML tags. What is the easiest way to do this?

E.g.

If I divided 123.34 by 60, I would get 2.055 and by adding the HTML tags again, I would get back a string with

```
"<b><i>2.055</i></b>"
```

(Example 2)

Comment: Let’s get the input constraints clear. Base on your example, input is (1) always one-liner, no extra whitespace, (2) could be parent-child struct, but no sibling presents. Is this the case for your input?

Comment: One-liner, no extra whitespace, no parent-child construct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a regex and a replacer function instead - match digits and return the replaced substring:

```js
var string = "<b><i>123.34</i></b>";
const newString = string.replace(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/, match => (match / 60).toFixed(5));
console.log(newString);
```